# How to add /usr/local/bin in $PATH on Mac

Tags: macos, git, node.js, path, profile

When I do 'open .profile' in the terminal I have the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Now I installed node.js for Mac and it says,

> Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.

How can I add `/usr/local/bin` to export `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin`?

Comment: I have voted to re-open this quesiton. It is about Node.js as well as Git (which is a tool that programmers use).

Comment: Yeah. If not here, where.

Comment: Minor bit of information: I don't know about earlier versions of OS X, but as of Yosemite at least, /usr/local/bin is included in $PATH by default.  You can check what's in your $PATH by running echo $PATH.

Comment: MacOS generates PATH (partly) from /etc/paths, which is where you'll find /usr/local/bin listed, as well as /usr/bin, /bin, /usr/sbin, and /sbin. See Also (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79306

Comment: echo $PATH will print your path. If you see /usr/local/bin between some colons, then it's in your path. source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19202049/1459653

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The `PATH` variable holds a list of directories separated by colons, so if you want to add more than one directory, just put a colon between them:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

That syntax works in any Bourne-compatible shell (sh, ksh, bash, zsh...). But zsh, which is the default shell in recent versions of MacOS, also exposes the PATH another way - as a variable named (lowercase) `$path`, which is an array instead of a single string. So you can do this instead:

```
path+=(/usr/local/git/bin /usr/local/bin)
```

In either case, you may want to check to make sure the directory isn't already in the PATH before adding it. Here's what that looks like using the generic syntax:

```
for dir in /usr/local/git/bin /usr/local/bin; do
   case "$PATH" in 
     $dir:*|*:$dir:*|*:$dir) :;; # already there, do nothing
     *) PATH=$PATH:$dir          # otherwise add it
   esac
done
```

And here's a zsh-specific version:

```
for dir in /usr/local/git/bin /usr/local/bin; do
  if (( ${path[(i)$dir]} > $#path )); then
    path+=($dir)
  fi
done
```

But in Zsh you can also just mark the array vars as accepting only unique entries:

```
typeset -TU PATH path
```

and even make your own pathlike variables mirrored in arrays:

```
typeset -TU PYTHONPATH pythonpath
```

Comment: While you can do this, it's not the OS X way. Paths on OS X are built using `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, called from the default `/etc/profile`. Start at `man path_helper` then add your paths in files in `/etc/paths.d`. You will find that pretty much every path setting example from other OSs includes `$PATH` because none of them seem to be able to commit to being the first one in the chain...

Comment: I was just answering the question of how to add multiple directories to the PATH.  You could also create multiple entries in `/etc/paths.d` or a single entry with multiple directories, one per line, but that doesn't help you at the prompt, and is just an indirect way of accomplishing the same thing. Plus, even though the question is tagged `osx`, this approach has the advantage of working on Linux and other UNIX-like systems as well.

Comment: The problem I find on Linux is that's it's horribly inconsistent and not a good example to follow. You'll find different sources telling you to use .profile, .bashrc, /etc/profile, /etc/environment and so on, and none of them want to take responsibility of saying "this is the right place to set the system path", so you end up taking the cross-your-fingers-and-hope approach of tacking $PATH onto everything, especially programatically. Install npm from homebrew and the paths work magically because it does it the right way.

Comment: Thanks - worked for me. I confirmed it by running `node --version`

Comment: Thanks a lot... I didn't know about the ZSH version. I come from a `bash` background and never took the time to learn ZSH. Good to know!

Comment: To be clear, the bash version works fine in zsh. But zsh also exposes PATH (and other pathlike variables, including CDPATH, FPATH, and MODULE_PATH) as arrays for easier manipulation.

Answer (score 23):

Try placing $PATH at the end.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 6):

To make the edited value of path persists in the next sessions

```
cd ~/
touch .bash_profile
open .bash_profile
```

That will open the .bash_profile in editor, write inside the following after adding what you want to the path separating each value by colon.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:
```

Save, exit, restart your terminal and enjoy

Comment: You need to add $PATH to the right hand side as well, otherwise you will lose access to all Linux commands

Comment: @HishamAfzalAhamed I added it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem with you.

cd to ../etc/ 
then use ls to make sure your "paths" file is in ,
vim paths, add "/usr/local/bin" at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to find this neat

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d   # was optional in my case
echo /usr/local/git/bin  | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/mypath1
```

Comment: https://scriptingosx.com/2017/05/where-paths-come-from/

Answer (score 2):

**In MAC OS Catalina,** 
this are the steps that worked for me, all the above solutions did help but didn't solve my problem.

1. check node --version, still the old one in use.
2. cd ~/
3. atom .bash_profile
4. Remove the $PATH pointing to old node
   version, in my case it was /usr/local/bin/node/@node8
5. Add & save this to $PATH instead "export
   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin"
6. Close all applications using node (terminal, simulator, browser expo etc)
7. restart terminal and check node --version

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal in Mac under Applications>Utilities ( Press command+shift+. to see hidden Utilities folder under Applications)

1. put command >sudo vi /etc/paths
2. Press key I to go in insert mode
3. Add following in new line if not already there  /usr/local/bin
4. Press escape key to come out of edit mode.
5. Enter :wq to save and close editor. Or Press :q to close with out saving.
   6.Then restart terminal
6. Put commands to see installed node version

> node -v