# Making sure /usr/local/bin is in my $PATH on mac

Tags: macos, node.js

I've installed node.js for Macintosh using the lastest installer for Macintosh.  I now want to check that /usr/local/bin is in my $PATH, as the installer instructed. I've opened up the Terminal application and researched help on the net, but I'm lost, as to how to accomplish the above, then start the node.js process. Can anyone clear this up?   Thank you for very much.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is automatically added to `$PATH` by `/etc/profile` from `/etc/paths`, so you never have to worry about adding this yourself.

Answer (score 203):

`echo $PATH` will print your path. If you see `/usr/local/bin` between some colons, then it's in your path.

Answer (score 90):

open terminal and type the command below

```
echo $PATH
```

You should see something like this

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

the presence of `/usr/local/bin` in the output means you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

To determine if `usr/local/bin` is included in `$PATH` open your terminal and run `echo $PATH`. If you see `usr/local/bin` in the output then you're good to go.

If you do not see `usr/local/bin` in the output, you can add it to your `$PATH` by opening your `~/.zprofile` and adding the following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```