# Installing Python on Mac after installing Homebrew

Tags: python

I am installing python on mac OS X El Capitan,the manual(http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/) says "Once you’ve installed Homebrew, insert the Homebrew directory at the top of your PATH environment variable. You can do this by adding the following line at the bottom of your ~/.profile file ".I am stuck here as i cannot find the ~/.profile file . Please help !

Comment: You can also put it in `~/.bash_profile`, depending on how you plan on using it; otherwise you'll need to create a `.profile` file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you searched StackOverflow or SuperUser at all before asking? Editing `.profile` and `.bash_profile` and the like is incredibly common. Here's an example question that goes over many ways to set environment variables on Mac OSX for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x

Comment: or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025980/how-to-add-usr-local-bin-in-path-on-mac