# How Can i unistall Python from Yosemite?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want  to unistall Python in my Mac.
I tried  to removed it from 
`/Library/Frameworks/`  
using
`sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`
and and from **Applications** too.
But yet i have 
`Python 2.7.10` 
when i use 
`Python -V`

How i can delete and unistall Python from my mac please?

Thanks.

Comment: Python is part of MacOS, I don't believe you can *remove* it without messing up the OS... You don't specify *why* you want to do it, but an educated guess is that [this](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) may help.

Comment: I installed python3.5.1 but when i use Python -V i have already 2.7.10

Comment: What about `python3 -V`? Or using a `virtualenv`?

Comment: in  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions   i have just 3.5 but Pythob -V give me 2.7.10, i'm really confused

Comment: python3 -V give me 3.5 but virtualenv use System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py"

Comment: What about `python3 -m virtualenv venv`?

Comment: Also, `/usr/bin/python` is most likely the executable you are running. Not sure what deleting that Framework folder does because it doesn't exist on my Mac

Comment: python3 -m virtualenv venv
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3: No module named virtualenv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not remove the system python. Consider it part of the operating system, and note that OS upgrades may restore that folder.

Instead, what it sounds like is that you want to have multiple python versions installed at the same time. There are several ways of doing this. The short version is that

1. The files have to be somewhere on your machine
2. Your `PATH` has to point to this new python
3. (optional) in the case of running python3, you may wish for `python` to execute python3.

Let's solve these problems one at a time.

### Installing python

It appears that you already have a version of python 3.5 installed, but you can also install it with `brew` or `pyenv`

To use `brew`, see these instructions: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

`pyenv` is a brew package, so to use it, you would first install brew and then install a version of python. See: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x

### Fixing the path

`$PATH` is an environment variable that is a list of directories. To see your current path, type in `echo $PATH` into a terminal. Each directory is delimited by a semicolon(`:`). When you type `python` in the terminal, the computer goes through each directory, in order, until it finds a file named python. So, this is why trying to execute `python` gives you the system python instead of the one you downloaded.

There are a couple ways of fixing this. Instead of running `python`, you could give an explicit path to wherever your new python binary is (for example `/usr/local/bin/python3` would launch the binary of python installed by `brew`.

Typing a path manually every time is hard, and not all applications do this, so one option would be to add your new directory to $PATH. See: [How to add /usr/local/bin in $PATH on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025980/how-to-add-usr-local-bin-in-path-on-mac) . This is a great option if you want to add a new `python3` (since it doesn't exist in the original OS), but doesn't help if you want to override the existing python

The other (better) option is to use virtual environments to *temporarily* change your PATH so that you can run the version of python that you want, without breaking other applications. This option also would let you run `python` and have it launch either python2 or python3 respectively. There are a few ways to get `virtualenv` working. You can read more here: https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

If you have `brew` installed, I would `brew install python python-virtualenvwrapper`

Hope this helps!