# boxfuse: command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudcaptain

I am integrating AWS and using boxfuse.

- I set up the [boxfuse](https://console.cloudcaptain.sh/#/getStarted) account.
- I install the boxfuse client.
- I connect the AWS account.

When I type in `terminal` :- boxfuse -v, it shows me error:-

> boxfuse: command not found

How to install and deploy web services on mac machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Boxfuse installation directory to the PATH.

Windows: [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

macOS: [How to add /usr/local/bin in $PATH on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025980/how-to-add-usr-local-bin-in-path-on-mac)

Linux: [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux)

Comment: In my system, boxfuse is located at software -> boxfuse. I run the following command in terminal:- `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:software/boxfuse`. But I am facing same error.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a leading slash? `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/software/boxfuse` Alternatively you can always use the full path.