# How to upgrade python on mac if multiple versions (including upgraded version) are already installed?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, homebrew, upgrade

I upgraded `pip` using the command `pip3 install --upgrade pip`; then, the following was printed in the terminal window:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th,
2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021.
pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
```

Searching online about the right way to upgrade python on a mac lead me to two sources ([1](https://jun711.github.io/devops/how-to-install-python3-on-mac-os/#homebrew)) and [(2)](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac). The second source mentions modifying the `.profile` and bash script; these are both things I am having trouble understanding, despite some help from similar questions on these stack exchange forums like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461201/how-do-i-edit-path-bash-profile-on-osx) and [that](https://superuser.com/questions/313275/where-to-create-a-profile-on-mac-os-x). But, using suggestions from the first source, I think I've identified a potential future problem (for which I read virtual venv may be a good fix). Specifically,

```
$ which python 
/usr/bin/python

$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3

$ brew info python
python@3.8: stable 3.8.5 (bottled)
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5 (4,331 files, 66.8MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2020-09-23 at 04:16:21
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/python@3.8.rb
License: Python-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gdbm ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, readline ✔, sqlite ✔, xz ✔
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/libexec/bin

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

See: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
==> Analytics
install: 435,972 (30 days), 1,606,776 (90 days), 3,198,770 (365 days)
install-on-request: 158,335 (30 days), 466,841 (90 days), 519,965 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

I think this means I have python 2, python 3.5, and python 3.8 installed on my mac. I tried upgrading my python version using the multiple versions of following command (ie, `python`, `python3`, `python3.8`, etc):

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade python
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python
```

I have installed python 3.8, but I'm apparently running 3.5; how do I upgrade my version of python? And how do I "clean this mess up"? In case it's relevant, I'm running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, and the only text-editor I like/use is Atom (please no suggestions regarding vim).

**EDIT #1:**

After following [the steps from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025980/how-to-add-usr-local-bin-in-path-on-mac/53743993#53743993), the following was opened in TextEdit.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

I notice that it says `Python 3.5` at the top. Do I over-write the given path `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"` with `PATH=/usr/local/bin`? I would like to run python 3.8; will this do what I want it to?

**EDIT #2:**

As suggested in the edited answer, running `grep PATH $HOME/.*` in the terminal outputs the following in the terminal window:

```
grep: /Users/username/.bash_sessions: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.cache: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.config: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.cups: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.git: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.idlerc: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.lightkurve-cache: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.local: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.matplotlib: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.npm: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.nvm: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.oracle_jre_usage: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.ssh: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.subversion: Is a directory
grep: /Users/username/.vnc: Is a directory
```

So, I search for the directory containing python 3.5. `Frameworks` is not listed if I `ls` while in `/Users/username/Library/`, so I search elsewhere. But this worries me because I saw `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"` (from edit #1).

```
$ pwd
/Users/username

$ cd .local/
$ ls 
share

$ cd share
$ ls
virtualenvs

$ cd virtualenvs
$ ls
PyCodes-_a3khG54    

$ cd PyCodes-_a3khG54
$ ls
bin include lib src
```

The directory `src` is empty; `include` contains `python3.5m` and `lib` contains `python3.5`.

```
$ cd bin
$ ls

activate        f2py            python
activate.csh        f2py3           python-config
activate.fish       f2py3.5         python3
activate_this.py    pip         python3.5
easy_install        pip3            wheel
easy_install-3.5    pip3.5
```

Shouldn't there be a file here that I can edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you show from:

```
brew info python
```

tells you the answer!

If I paraphrase, it says:

> If you want to run **Python 3.8** and **pip** by typing `python3` and `pip3`, you need to put `/usr/local/bin` first on your `PATH`. If, instead, you want to run them by typing `python` or `pip`, i.e. without a version, you need to put `/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/libexec/bin` first on your `PATH`.

It's not that straightforward to say where to change your `PATH` because there are many possibilities as to where it is set. Your best bet is probably to look in all *"dotfiles"* in your HOME directory, so:

```
grep PATH $HOME/.*
```

Then you need to open the most likely looking file, and add just after the last place it is set, something like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

To actually activate it, the simplest is probably to start a new Terminal and run:

```
echo $PATH
```

If it looks correct, close the Terminal with the old PATH else you'll confuse yourself. If it looks incorrect, or causes an error, immediately close the new Terminal window and retry the edit in the original Terminal.

---

If you want to know what you are actually running when you type `python`, and `pip`, run:

```
type python
type pip
```

---

If you want to know what you are actually running when you type `python3`, and `pip3`, run:

```
type python3
type pip3
```

---

You can interpret the outputs of the last few `type` commands like this:

- if they contain the word `local` near the start, probably `/usr/local/XXX`, they are likely supplied by **homebrew** or something you have compiled or installed yourself,
- if they start with `/Library` or contain the word `Frameworks`, they are probably supplied by Apple and fairly recent,
- if they start with `/usr/bin` but **without** the word `local`, they are probably older Apple-supplied binaries,
- if it says your command is *"aliased"*, that means you have a command like `alias python="something crazy"` somewhere in your *"dotfiles"* (see above). Personally, I would remove that as it just adds another layer of indirection and confusion... YMMV on this one.

Never delete or alter anything supplied by Apple - else future **macOS** upgrades may fail.

---

So, hopefully we have established that you need to either use `python` and `pip`, or use `python3` and `pip3` and that they should match, i.e. that when you install a package you are installing it in a place usable by the **Python** interpreter you use. So, an example of a *"matching"* installation looks like this:

```
type python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3

python3 -V
Python 3.8.5

pip3 -V
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

type pip3
pip3 is hashed (/usr/local/bin/pip3)
```

Notice how both my binaries contain `local` in their names, so they both come from **homebrew** and how the **Python** version matches the version in the `pip3 -V` command so I can be sure I am installing in the correct place for my **Python** interpreter.

---

Why is it hard to say where to edit your `PATH`? The answer is that it depends on many things. It depends on your shell, so you might see the advice to run `echo $SHELL`, but that only tells you your default shell, not your current shell, which you can find with `ps -o comm= $$`. But your login shell could be `bash` and you may have execed `fish` in your bash profile. Or you may use `iTerm2` or `Terminal` or `xterm` and you may have changed your shell in the *"Preferences"* for that terminal program.

Comment: "If you want to run Python 3.8 and pip by typing `python3` and `pip3`, you need to put `/usr/local/bin` first on your `PATH`".


[This source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387695/add-to-python-path-mac-os-x) explains how to do it, but I don't really understand how to do this. I imagine there is a file that I can open using a text-editor (like Atom) and add `PATH=/usr/local/bin` at the bottom of it; is this correct? If so, how do I find this file?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to gauge where people are at sometimes. I added some further explanation. Please have another look.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help! I have yet to figure it out, but I think you have provided enough information for the average person to find your answer helpful.

Comment: I think I have found the correct file. It looks like: 

`# Setting PATH for Python 3.5`

`# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave`

`PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"`

`# export PATH` (I replaced this line w the one below)

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

`export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"`

`[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm`

`[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion`

The edit makes no difference. What can I try next?

Comment: Ran out of characters; `$ echo $PATH` returns the following: `/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin`