# I am encountering an issue in trying to install PIP3 for my Mac terminal

Tags: python, machine-learning, terminal, pip, pyenv-virtualenv

I successfully installed:

```
python3 -m pip install gluoncv
```

Then I successfully installed:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

But I encountered an issue `zsh: command not found: virtualenv` when I tried to install the following:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 python27
```

What remedy would you suggest? My goal is to instal PIP and use MLModels with Xcode. I'm a beginner programmer, so hand holding & talking to me like I'm 5 year old is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: When you use `pip` to install a module that includes an executable command, that command is usually installed in `~/.local/bin`.  Is that directory included in your shell path environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try
`python3 -m virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 python27`

As a rule of thumb, if you installed it through `python3 -m pip`, you run it using `python3 -m ...`

Answer (score 0):

> And here's a zsh-specific version:
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11025993

The `PATH` variable holds a list of directories separated by colons, so if you want to add more than one directory, just put a colon between them:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
```